# Tootltip is coming half for dynamic data.

Tags: javascript, html

I am using img tag and using `title` to set tooltip. Mouseover. Here is my code.

```
var test = "United State of America";
myText = "<img src='image.png' style='vertical-align:middle' title = "+test+" onClick='myfunc(event," + JSON.stringify(someJson) + ")'></img>";
```

But in this case my tooltip is showing only United. Do I need to use any other attribute to show complete tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = "United State of America";
myText = "<img src='image.png' style='vertical-align:middle' title = '"+test+"' onClick='myfunc(event," + JSON.stringify(someJson) + ")'></img>";
```

You will need to enclose the title's value.